# Missing CSS/JS in the Control Panel

Tags: installation

The issue I am experiencing is very similar to the one described here: [link](https://craftcms.com/support/missing-cp-css-js).  The fix described there does not work.

Here is what happens when I request a resource from that page directly using curl:

```
$ curl -v 'http://localhost/admin/resources/js/craft.js?d=1474612391'
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 80 (#0)
> GET /admin/resources/js/craft.js?d=1474612391 HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx
< Date: Fri, 23 Sep 2016 07:07:59 GMT
< Content-Type: application/javascript; charset=utf-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.2
< Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="craft.js"
< X-Sendfile: [CENSORED]/craft/app/resources/js/compressed/craft.js
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Here is some version info:

- Linux: 16.04 LTS (Xenial Xerus)
- PHP: 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.2
- nginx: 1.10.0

Here is a [link](https://gist.github.com/kenzie/5811327) to my nginx config (approximately).

Here is a screenshot of what the page looks like:

[image]

Comment: The cURL output looks like it actually works... you get a 200OK and the correct response headers.  Do you get a 200OK from the browser as well for those CSS/JS files?

Comment: Yes I get 200 in browser as well.  But the files are empty.  The source files are intact on the server.  I turned dev mode on and opened up craft/storage/runtime/logs/craft.log and everything looks normal

Answer (score 1):

The setting useXSendFile was set to true.  I changed this setting to false and everything works now.  Looks like this [guide](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/xsendfile/) could help to get things working when this setting is set to true.